# Does every continuous-time filter have a state-space representation?

Tags: filters, state-space

Given a continuous-time filter with impulse response $h(t)$, is it possible to represent any $h(t)$ in state-space form?

More precisely, given the state-space representation of a single-input single-output LTI system $$\dot x(t) = ax(t) + bu(t)$$ where $x(t)$ represents the system's state and $u(t)$ represents its input, the output of this system is then $$y(t) = cx(t) + du(t)$$ For simplicity, suppose that $d = 0$, such that $y(t) = cx(t)$. We can solve the state-equation for $x(t)$ to obtain $$x(t) = x(0)e^{at} + \int_0^t u(\lambda) be^{a(t - \lambda)} \text{d}\lambda$$ and the corresponding output is
\begin{align}
y(t) &= cx(t) \\
&= cx(0)e^{at} + c\int_0^t u(\lambda) be^{a(t - \lambda)} \text{d}\lambda
\end{align}
Because we want to find the output of this system in response to an impulse, such that $u(t) = \delta (t)$, then the impulse response $h(t)$ is
\begin{align}
h(t) &= cx(0)e^{at} + c\int_0^t \delta(\lambda) be^{a(t - \lambda)} \text{d}\lambda \\
&= cx(0)e^{at} + cbe^{at}
\end{align}
Because $h(t)$ takes this form, then it seems to me that it would not be possible to represent every $h(t)$ in state-space form. For example, what would we set $a,b,$ and $c$ to be such that $h(t) = \sin(t)$? I'm interested to know if I'm wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, yes and no.  Yes, but you may not be able to recognize it in the end -- or find an agreed-upon and useful representation for it.

If the system (a filter is just a system, so I'm going to use the more general term here) is linear, time-invariant, and has discrete states (i.e., it can be represented by ordinary differential equations), then you can represent the filter in "regular old" state space*:

$$\begin{align}
\mathbf{\dot x}(t) &= \mathbf A \mathbf x(t) + \mathbf B \mathbf u(t)\\
\mathbf y(t) &= \mathbf C \mathbf x(t) + \mathbf D \mathbf u(t)
\end{align}.\tag 1$$

If the system is linear, time **varying**, and has discrete states (i.e., it can be represented by ordinary differential equations), then you can represent the filter in something easily recognizable if you know time-invariant state space:

$$\begin{align}
\mathbf{\dot x}(t) &= \mathbf A(t) \mathbf x(t) + \mathbf B(t) \mathbf u(t)\\
\mathbf y(t) &= \mathbf C(t) \mathbf x(t) + \mathbf D(t) \mathbf u(t)
\end{align}.\tag 2$$

Note that the system in (2) can still have an impulse response -- it'll just be time-varying.  I.e., instead of being $h(\tau)$ or $h(t)$, it'll be $h(\tau, t)$.  See [Time-varying "impulse response"](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/41839/time-varying-impulse-response) for details.

A system can be linear (and time varying or not), and described by partial differential equations or by equations with lag in them.  I.e., for a super-simple case you can describe a filter where

$$y(t) = \frac 1 T \int_0^T u(t - \tau) d\tau. \tag 3$$

It's linear, it's time-invariant, its impulse response is

$$h(t) = \begin{cases}
\frac 1 T & 0 \le t \le T \\
0 & \mathrm {otherwise}
\end{cases}, \tag 4$$

but if there's a state-space representation for it then it's obscure and I don't know it. I did a search and ran across some research papers from decades ago (1980's) that imply that there is a notation, but I don't know how common it is, or what tools exist (beyond simulation) to analyze such systems.

A system can be **non**-linear, and described in state space, in something sensible.  This is a general form you'll see in the literature.  If it's not time varying, just leave off the dependency on $t$ in $f$ and $g$:

$$\begin{align}
\mathbf{\dot x}(t) &= f(\mathbf x, \mathbf u, t)\\
\mathbf y(t) &= g(\mathbf x, \mathbf u, t)
\end{align}.\tag 5$$

Note that this system does *not*, in general, have an impulse response -- yet you can still represent it in state space.

For the specific case where $h(t)=sin(t)$, that can be expressed as a second-order ordinary linear differential equation
$$ \ddot x(t)=−x(t)+u(t). \tag 6$$
*A* state-space realization of (6) is
$$\begin{align}
\dot {\mathbf x} &= \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix} \mathbf x + \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix} \mathbf u \\
y &= \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\end{bmatrix} \mathbf x
\end{align}. \tag 7$$

* A long time ago I wrote out something in state space for a coworker, who said "oh, you were educated on the east coast (of the US)!"  Apparently, using A, B, C, and D for your matrices is an east coast thing, while F, G, and H (I'm not sure what folks use for the feed-through matrix in that system) is a west coast thing.

Comment: It seems then that only $h(t)$’s that are linear only have a state-space representation. For example, $h(t) = \sin(t)$ doesn’t have a state space representation. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: An impulse response is a signal, more or less.  As such, it's neither linear nor nonlinear.  And, a system with an impulse response of $h(t) = sin(t)$ can be expressed as a second-order ordinary linear differential equation ($\ddot x(t) = -x(t) + u(t)$, if I'm not mistaken).  That system _does_ have a state-space representation.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is "yes" but not a **unique** state space representation.

There is a unique representation that guarantees observability and a unique representation that guarantees controllability. And for higher orders, a zillion other possible representations.

Comment: If so, then how would you choose $a,b,$ and $c$, which I mentioned in my question, so that $h(t) = \sin(t)$?

Comment: Admittedly, I did not consider your question well.  Not just ***any*** $h(t)$, but an $h(t)$ that is commensurate with a 1st-order LTI system.  And the lower the order, the fewer degrees of freedom you have.  So, I think you can represent any impulse response of the form $$ h(t) = h(0) e^{-\alpha t} $$ with $d=0$.  $a$ will be a function of $\alpha$ and $(b \times c)$ will be a function of $h(0)$.  You still have an infinite number of choices for $b$ or $c$ but you are constrained to their product.

Comment: And when $u(t)$ is the label we have for the input, I do not know what a good letter to use for the unit step function.   I don't like "$H(t)$" for Heaviside, because $H(s)$ is the Laplace Transform of $h(t)$.